# Question on Showing the dimensions of a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

---

For the first part I put the matrix into echleon form :

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&2&3\\0&1&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

**And then:**

$r(A)=2\implies \dim(A)=4-2=2$

^^ Is my presentation **correct?**

---

The second part is the biggest problem. I don't know how to do. Please help.

---

Also if anyone  knows a good book or a good website to **master** this chapter so that I can answer many questions easily, let me know. Would be very helpful to me.

Comment: For the second part: If $M:\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ is non-singular, what does this imply about the kernel of $M$ and thus the range of $M$?

Comment: If $M$ is non-singular, how do the dimensions of the domain of $M$ and the range of $M$ relate?

Comment: @AndrewLedesma I don't know :( I know that M has an inverse. What does domain of a matrix mean?

Comment: The domain of $M$ is the space that $M$ acts on, i.e the domain of $A$ above is $\mathbb{R}^4$.
If $\{v_i\}$ in the domain of $M$ are linearly independent, what do you know about $\{Mv_i\}$? (consider applying $M^{-1}$ to $\sum_n Mc_nv_n$ for $c_n$ arbitrary constants.)

Comment: @Krijn what about its null space?

Comment: Also, Krijn and I are getting at the same point. If $Mv=0$, what does that tell you about $v$? What does that tell you about $M$?

Comment: @AndrewLedesma im thinking...

Comment: @AndrewLedesma It tells me that $v$ is all the set of vectors that when M is multiplied with gives 0. Which means $v$ is a span of vectors (has a basis).

Comment: But $M$ is invertible, try and see what that tells you about $v$ satisfying $Mv=0$.

Comment: @AndrewLedesma We can put $M^-1 M v= M^-1 0$ which gives $v=0$? :)

Comment: Yes, ie the kernel of M is zero. That tells you something about M which should be all you need to finish off.

Comment: When you say $\dim(A)$ (which makes no sense, subspaces have dimensions, matrices do not), you appear to mean $\dim(\ker(A))$.